# How can I show the above text after jumping to a specific part of a page?

Tags: html

I made a table of contents with some titles to jump down to the target info because the post is too long, almost 4,000 words.

The jumping works fine, it goes to the part it is supposed to go but somehow it doesn't show the text that is above the specific targeted line. I can't scroll up because there is no text.

How can I prevent it from "erasing" the above text?

I used the following code:

```
<a href="#section-01">Click here to see section 01</a>
<a href="#section-02">Click here to see section 02</a>
<a href="#section-03">Click here to see section 03</a>

<a id="section-01">This is some info for section 01</a>
<a id="section-02">This is some info for section 02</a>
<a id="section-03">This is some info for section 03</a>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put some `<br>`'s among the tags?

And don't use the `<a>` without a href. Try instead a `<span>`.

```
    <a href="#section-01">Click here to see section 01</a><br>
    <a href="#section-02">Click here to see section 02</a><br>
    <a href="#section-03">Click here to see section 03</a><br>

    <span id="section-01">This is some info for section 01</span><br>
    <span id="section-02">This is some info for section 02</span><br>
    <span id="section-03">This is some info for section 03</span><br>
```

Comment: Yes, I've also tried that and it just keeps erasing content.

I think it has something to do this css but I don't know what part I need to change. This is the blog:

https://pruexx1.blogspot.com/p/tables-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to interpret your question, in straight html there should be no "erasing".

In html there's a `<section>` tag that might be a better choice for each section than `<a>`.

`<section id="section-01" >
  <h1>This is the title for section 1</h1>
  <p>This is the content of section 1</p>
</section>`

Comment: Thank you for replying.No matter if I use a or section, it's the same mistake.

With "erasing" I mean that when it goes to part 3, it shows the part 3 at the top with no more text above it so you're not able to scroll up just down.

It's like the text of parts 1 and 2 just got erased.

You need to reload the page to see the whole post with all the 3 parts.

The blog is in blogger and here's the page:

https://pruexx1.blogspot.com/p/tables-testing.html